# What is the correct way to call a static method in PHP?

Tags: php, class, static

When I call my static method by `static::some_method();` it gives me the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM, expecting T_VARIABLE in /some/path/SomeClass.class.php on line 15
```

If I replace static with the class name it works of course, but what is the correct way to call a static method without using the classname?

Comment: You need to use the class name. There's no other way around it AFAIK.

Comment: That makes no sense, how could PHP know which class's method you mean? Do you mean a "normal" global function? Then you may not declare the function inside the class.

Comment: Check out your code again and double make sure your make have no syntax error especially in strings case. Use proper escape sequence ."\"

Comment: you have a class like Class SomeClass { static public function some_method() { static::some_other_method(); } }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are within the context of the class then

```
self::method();
static::method();
```

...will both work, with different behaviors related to [`late static binding`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).

If you are not in the context of a class, then you need to use the classname the method belongs to:

```
SomeClass::method();
```

Otherwise you'll get that goofy hebrew error, `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM`, which means "double colon" in English.

Comment: The wird part is, I am calling within the class and normally it works, but changing hosting I got this error. I am using PHP 5.2.17 is that the problem?

Comment: Yup reading the documentation from your link it does start since 5.3, will accept this as the answer within 3 minutes

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
ClassName::some_method()
```

to invoke static method (not using `static` keyword) or, if you are inside one that class, use

```
self::some_method()
```

where `self` is a keyword (i.e. inside another method).

Comment: I am using it, inside the class itself. However the self keyword will call the old method when it has been overwritten by a different class. So I used static and get_called_class to get the latest class if you know what I mean.

Comment: Ah, I haven't seen >=PHP 5.3 `static::` keyword use in that context (with double colon). Nice to know.